# NestJS Kafka send event from server to all clients

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, nestjs

How do I send an event from the server to the client or to all clients? How do I get a server instance in the controller at all?

I need to send an event to the client from the server, without a request from the client side. The client listens, I send.

The point is that I implemented the architecture. Api-gateway sends a request to a microservice and gets a response. I need to implement sending event from microservice to api-gateway. In api-gateway I got a client instance in the controller, how do I get the same instance in the microservice? The controller in my microservice only listens to messages and sends a response. How can I do the same in api-gateway? So that Api-gateway listens to the event and microservice sends messages there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, altough you didn't provide enough details in your question, I'll pretend, based on your question tags, you're trying to use NestJS microservices and Kafka.

First of all, take a look at Nest's Microservices documentation, you should first understand how that works before trying to use it:
https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics

You might also want to create a hybrid application if you're not going to exclusively use Kafka as an entrypoint:
https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application

That said, still based on your tags, here's a brief guide on how to implement Kafka on NestJS using the same knowledge you aquired reading about microservices and hybrid applications: https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/kafka

You should be able to implement simple but functional application with those documentations I mentioned, but for anything else, you should provide more details on your question (like what you need, what you tried, some code etc).

Comment: I need to send an event to the client from the server, without a request from the client side. The client listens, I send.

Comment: @АтчановАлександр Whatever you're using to send is still considered "a client", whether that's a Kafka client or an HTTP client, is not really relevant to the Kafka consumer

Answer (score 0):

> Kafka send event ... To all clients

> How do I send an event from the server

Kafka doesn't send. Clients poll.

If you deploy each Kafka consumer client application with a unique `group.id`, for the set of topics you're producing to, they will all uniquely consume the data. Otherwise, if each deployment shares a id, they all consume unique partitions of the topic, never getting the same event to all the clients

NestJS uses KafkaJS - https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming

> without a request from the client side

Unclear what this means. Even if the NestJS server is randomly generating data, you'll still need to use a Kafka *producer client* to send data to the *Kafka server*

> get a server instance in the controller

The Kafka server? You wouldn't. You'd pass the bootstrap server string (via external config) into a producer or consumer instance, which then can be given to a controller

Comment: I did, how do I connect the producer to the module? how do I get an instance of the producer in the constructor?

Comment: @АтчановАлександр There is a very similar question here that uses NestJS with a producer https://stackoverflow.com/q/71892131/2308683

Comment: no friend. The point is that I implemented the architecture.  Api-gateway sends a request to a microservice and gets a response. I need to implement sending event from microservice to api-gateway. In api-gateway I got a client instance in the controller, how do I get the same instance in the microservice? The controller in my microservice only listens to messages and sends a response. How can I do the same in api-gateway? So that Api-gateway listens to the event and microservice sends messages there.

Comment: @АтчановАлександр Without seeing your code it's hard to help you. I don't know nestjs. As answered, you cannot use Kafka to send data between services directly. It **does not** help you with request/response architecture. You'd send from one service to Kafka. Your other service then uses a consumer listener to get the data from Kafka. If you want to send data between services directly, you don't need Kafka